# PHP + SQL Query: Selecting Enum Values

Tags: php, mysql, enums

I'm running into a weird situation with a PHP execution of a SQL query that maybe someone can shed a little light on:

I have a query that says:

```
"SELECT COLUMN_TYPE 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = $table 
 AND COLUMN_NAME = $column"
```

The query should return a string: `enum('A','B'[,'C'...])` when executed (as it does when running the query from the command line. `$table` and `$column` are passed to the function making the query, and in my test case are proper – both exist as a table and column respectively. In this case, let's set `$table = 'profile'` and `$column = 'gender'`, to which the above SQL statement is returning the following error:

```
Unknown column 'profile' in 'where clause' in /registry/mysqldb.class.php on line 31
```

Line 31 is a caching function to cache queries until required, or triggering an error when the query fails. This works fine in every other case. I'm connected to the correct DB when the request is made.

My question is this: Why is 'profile' being interpreted as a column and causing the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it's because you are missing quotes around the variables. Try:

```
"SELECT COLUMN_TYPE
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$table' 
   AND COLUMN_NAME = '$column'"
```

Comment: Gah... Between the cutting, pasting, and undoing I must have lost them. I was wondering why it had worked, then suddenly didn't. Sorry for the stupid question!